# Can I backup or mirror an IMAP mailbox on Mac OS X?

Tags: email, imap

What is the easiest way to create a dump of an IMAP mailbox on a local drive using Mac OS X?

I would prefer a tool that can mirror an IMAP mailbox's structure to something that creates a massive archive file because the former would be faster and slimmer to do an incremental backup for. But any solution is welcome.

Comment: The simplest way is to move/copy the folder you want to the "On my Mac"

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using Unix tools, a few applications spring to mind:

- [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org)
- [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info)
- [Mailsync](http://mailsync.sourceforge.net)

imapsync isn't open source but the others are. You may also find [this Ask Different thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/how-can-i-back-up-a-complete-imap-account) useful.